# how to force a fragment to save it's state (parent activity being only *paused*)

Tags: android, fragment, state, restore

I am developing a (custom) bottom action bar, managed through a fragment. The bottom bar is made of 5 buttons, and is shared by 3 activities (I want each individual activity to present this bar at the bottom of the screen).

[image: The look of the bottom action bar]

I would like to save/restore the state of the fragment in order to save buttons' state across activity changes (through startActivity(Intent) and so on).

However, when starting a child activity from a parent one, the first one is **not** destroyed and the state of the activity (and it's inner fragments) is **not** saved. In consequence, when my child activity starts, the state of it's bottom bar fragment is **not** restored.

## The code

The link between my activities :

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TicketPromo" />
<activity
    android:name=".SavingsActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TicketPromo" />
```

**My save / restore code :**

```
public class BottomBarFragment extends Fragment {

...

    // Indicates whether the buttons are enabled or not
    protected boolean isPromoFlashEnabled;
    protected boolean isCouponsModeEnabled;
    protected boolean isSavingsModeEnabled;
    protected boolean isSearchModeEnabled;
    protected boolean isAccountModeEnabled;

...

    /*
     * Save the state of buttons so they can be restored on the next screen.
     */

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
        // Save buttons' state
        state.putBoolean("isPromoFlashEnabled", isPromoFlashEnabled);
        state.putBoolean("isCouponsModeEnabled", isCouponsModeEnabled);
        state.putBoolean("isSavingsModeEnabled", isSavingsModeEnabled);
        state.putBoolean("isSearchModeEnabled", isSearchModeEnabled);
        state.putBoolean("isAccountModeEnabled", isAccountModeEnabled);
    }

    /*
     * Restore the state of buttons and call their trigger on the screen opener.
     */

    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle state) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(state);
        if (state == null) { return; }
        // Promo flash
        isPromoFlashEnabled = state.getBoolean("isPromoFlashEnabled", false);
        toggleActionButton(ActionButton.PromoFlash, isPromoFlashEnabled);
        screenOpenener.togglePromoFlashButton(isPromoFlashEnabled);

        // My coupons
        isCouponsModeEnabled = state.getBoolean("isCouponsModeEnabled", false);
        toggleActionButton(ActionButton.Coupons, isCouponsModeEnabled);
        screenOpenener.toggleMyCouponsButton(isCouponsModeEnabled);

        // My savings
        isSavingsModeEnabled = state.getBoolean("isSavingsModeEnabled", false);
        toggleActionButton(ActionButton.Savings, isSavingsModeEnabled);
        screenOpenener.toggleMySavingsButton(isSavingsModeEnabled);

        // Search mode
        isSearchModeEnabled = state.getBoolean("isSearchModeEnabled", false);
        toggleActionButton(ActionButton.Search, isSearchModeEnabled);
        screenOpenener.toggleSearchButton(isSearchModeEnabled);

        // My account
        isAccountModeEnabled = state.getBoolean("isAccountModeEnabled", false);
        toggleActionButton(ActionButton.Account, isAccountModeEnabled);
        screenOpenener.toggleMyAccountButton(isAccountModeEnabled);
    }

...
}
```

**The code to obtain a reference on the fragment when creating the activities** (the fragment is directly inserted in the activity's layout with `<fragment .../>` ) :

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
bottomBar = (BottomBarFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_bar);
```

## THE question

1. How to save the state of a fragment that is still attached to a **paused** activity
2. How to restore this state
3. Is there a link with `setRetainInstance(true)` or a hack regarding this?

## Edit, reworded question :

How to share a single fragment between two activities so the fragment is **not** destroyed, or at least so that it can be saved/restored across activities' lifecyle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using SharedPreferences when the first activity comes to be paused.

Not a great deal, just sad I couldn't use the native life cycle to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

**1- If your main activity gets in pause state your fragment should get in pause state to.**

> This corresponds to Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) and most of
>   the discussion there applies here as well. Note however: this method
>   may be called at any time before onDestroy(). There are many
>   situations where a fragment may be mostly torn down (such as when
>   placed on the back stack with no UI showing), but its state will not
>   be saved until its owning activity actually needs to save its state.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

**2- You could get the saved bundle at [onViewStateRestored](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored%28android.os.Bundle%29).**

> Called when all saved state has been restored into the view hierarchy
>   of the fragment. This can be used to do initialization based on saved
>   state that you are letting the view hierarchy track itself, such as
>   whether check box widgets are currently checked. This is called after
>   onActivityCreated(Bundle) and before onStart().

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored(android.os.Bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewStateRestored%28android.os.Bundle%29)

**3- If you set retain instance to TRUE the save and restore methods will only be called when the fragment was realy create/destroyed because when the flag is TRUE the first instance is "never" lost.**

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
>   re-creation (such as from a configuration change). This can only be
>   used with fragments not in the back stack. If set, the fragment
>   lifecycle will be slightly different when an activity is recreated:
>
> - onDestroy() will not be called (but onDetach() still will be, because the fragment is being detached from its current activity).
> - onCreate(Bundle) will not be called since the fragment is not being re-created.
> - onAttach(Activity) and onActivityCreated(Bundle) will still be called.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29)

Comment: If I understand, I should call `Activity.onSaveInstanceState(...)` __before__ starting my child Activity ?
That is to say, wait that the first is stopped, then calling startActivity(Intent) to launch the second ?

Comment: No @HNelson, the onSaveInstanceState and onViewStateRestored methods are called by Activity and Fragment flux itself, you just use overriding tham inside your Activities and Fragments.

Comment: Yea but the problem is that the onSaveInstanceState is **not** called because my first activity is **not** destroyed.
**@Android doc > Activity > Process Lifecycle**

Comment: So if you called a method who save the button state when you goes to another activity by start activity for result and apply button state back when back from activity? I'm not understanding when your button lost the state you tell if the activity and fragment are not destroyed.